# I can't import minecraft package in my java project

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

I'm creating a Minecraft Java plugin and to make it work I need to import a few packages, but when I put the ; in the end the string becomes gray (In the source code they are indicated with * after the string) and therefore it doesn't detect the packets, how can I fix it? A thousand thanks

P.S: Below you will find all the source code if you need it to help me

[Download](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3d01098c59ca445a85299c3c815975f420230502160343/4ceb9a681f0216deed3c3a1e343698e520230502160359/1153f7?trk=TRN_TDL_01&utm_campaign=TRN_TDL_01&utm_medium=email&utm_source=sendgrid)

Here the code of the program:

```java
package com.bizarrealex.aether;
import com.bizarrealex.aether.event.BoardCreateEvent;
import com.bizarrealex.aether.scoreboard.Board;
import com.bizarrealex.aether.scoreboard.BoardAdapter;
import com.bizarrealex.aether.scoreboard.BoardEntry;
import lombok.Getter; *
import org.bukkit.Bukkit; *
import org.bukkit.ChatColor; *
import org.bukkit.entity.Player; *
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler; *
import org.bukkit.event.EventPriority; *
import org.bukkit.event.Listener; *
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent; *
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerQuitEvent; *
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin; *
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable; *
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.DisplaySlot; *
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.Objective; *
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.Score; *
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.Scoreboard; *
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import static com.bizarrealex.aether.AetherOptions.defaultOptions;
/**
 * TODO: Add documentation to methods, etc
 * TODO: Fix inconsistent cooldown scores
 * TODO: Finish other board formats
 */
public class Aether implements Listener {

    @Getter
    BoardAdapter adapter;
    @Getter
    private JavaPlugin plugin;
    @Getter
    private AetherOptions options;

    public Aether(JavaPlugin plugin, BoardAdapter adapter, AetherOptions options) {
        this.options = options;
        this.plugin = plugin;

        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);

        setAdapter(adapter);
        run();
    }

    public Aether(JavaPlugin plugin, BoardAdapter adapter) {
        this(plugin, adapter, defaultOptions());
    }

    public Aether(JavaPlugin plugin) {
        this(plugin, null, defaultOptions());
    }

    private void run() {
        new BukkitRunnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (adapter == null) return;

                for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                    Board board = Board.getByPlayer(player);
                    if (board != null) {
                        List<String> scores = adapter.getScoreboard(player, board, board.getCooldowns());
                        List<String> translatedScores = new ArrayList<>();

                        if (scores == null) {

                            if (!board.getEntries().isEmpty()) {

                                for (BoardEntry boardEntry : board.getEntries()) {
                                    boardEntry.remove();
                                }

                                board.getEntries().clear();
                            }

                            continue;
                        }

                        for (String line : scores) {
                            translatedScores.add(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', line));
                        }

                        if (!options.scoreDirectionDown()) {
                            Collections.reverse(scores);
                        }

                        Scoreboard scoreboard = board.getScoreboard();
                        Objective objective = board.getObjective();

                        if (!(objective.getDisplayName().equals(adapter.getTitle(player)))) {
                            objective.setDisplayName(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', adapter.getTitle(player)));
                        }

                        outer:
                        for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++) {
                            String text = scores.get(i);
                            int position;
                            if (options.scoreDirectionDown()) {
                                position = 15 - i;
                            } else {
                                position = i + 1;
                            }

                            Iterator<BoardEntry> iterator = new ArrayList<>(board.getEntries()).iterator();
                            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                                BoardEntry boardEntry = iterator.next();
                                Score score = objective.getScore(boardEntry.getKey());

                                if (score != null && boardEntry.getText().equals(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', text))) {
                                    if (score.getScore() == position) {
                                        continue outer;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            int positionToSearch = options.scoreDirectionDown() ? 15 - position : position - 1;

                            iterator = board.getEntries().iterator();
                            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                                BoardEntry boardEntry = iterator.next();
                                int entryPosition = scoreboard.getObjective(DisplaySlot.SIDEBAR).getScore(boardEntry.getKey()).getScore();

                                if (!options.scoreDirectionDown()) {
                                    if (entryPosition > scores.size()) {
                                        iterator.remove();
                                        boardEntry.remove();
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                            BoardEntry entry = board.getByPosition(positionToSearch);

                            if (entry == null) {
                                new BoardEntry(board, text).send(position);
                            } else {
                                entry.setText(text).setup().send(position);
                            }

                            if (board.getEntries().size() > scores.size()) {
                                iterator = board.getEntries().iterator();
                                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                                    BoardEntry boardEntry = iterator.next();
                                    if ((!translatedScores.contains(boardEntry.getText())) || Collections.frequency(board.getBoardEntriesFormatted(), boardEntry.getText()) > 1) {
                                        iterator.remove();
                                        boardEntry.remove();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        adapter.onScoreboardCreate(player, scoreboard);

                        player.setScoreboard(scoreboard);
                    }
                }
            }
        }.runTaskTimerAsynchronously(plugin, 20L, 2L);
    }

    public void setAdapter(BoardAdapter adapter) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
        for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
            Board board = Board.getByPlayer(player);

            if (board != null) {
                Board.getBoards().remove(board);
            }

            Bukkit.getPluginManager().callEvent(new BoardCreateEvent(new Board(player, this, options), player));
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoinEvent(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
        if (Board.getByPlayer(event.getPlayer()) == null) {
            Bukkit.getPluginManager().callEvent(new BoardCreateEvent(new Board(event.getPlayer(), this, options), event.getPlayer()));
        }
    }

    @EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.HIGHEST)
    public void onPlayerQuitEvent(PlayerQuitEvent event) {
        Board board = Board.getByPlayer(event.getPlayer());
        if (board != null) {
            Board.getBoards().remove(board);
        }
    }

}
```

The output of the program if I build it:

```
7: java: package lombok does not exist
8: java: package org.bukkit does not exist
9: java: package org.bukkit does not exist
10: java: package org.bukkit.entity does not exist
11: java: package org.bukkit.event does not exist
12: java: package org.bukkit.event does not exist
13: java: package org.bukkit.event does not exist
14: java: package org.bukkit.event.player does not exist
15: java: package org.bukkit.event.player does not exist
16: java: package org.bukkit.plugin.java does not exist
17: java: package org.bukkit.scheduler does not exist
18: java: package org.bukkit.scoreboard does not exist
19: java: package org.bukkit.scoreboard does not exist
20: java: package org.bukkit.scoreboard does not exist
21: java: package org.bukkit.scoreboard does not exist
35: java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Listener
40: java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JavaPlugin
  location: class com.bizarrealex.aether.Aether
44: java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JavaPlugin
  location: class com.bizarrealex.aether.Aether
54: java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JavaPlugin
  location: class com.bizarrealex.aether.Aether
58: java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JavaPlugin
  location: class com.bizarrealex.aether.Aether
183: java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PlayerJoinEvent
  location: class com.bizarrealex.aether.Aether
190: java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PlayerQuitEvent
  location: class com.bizarrealex.aether.Aether
```

I searched if the package was wrong but couldn't find anything and, after a guy told me to do this, i pointed the package in the pom.xml file like this

```xml
<dependencies>
             <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
             <artifactId>bukkit</artifactId>
             <version>VERSION</version>
             <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

the complete code is this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

     <groupId>us.zonix.practice</groupId>
     <artifactId>Practice</artifactId>
     <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

     <properties>
         <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
     </properties>

     <repositories>
         <repository>
             <id>sk89q-repo</id>
             <url>http://maven.sk89q.com/repo/</url>
         </repository>

         <repository>
             <id>fawe-repo</id>
             <url>http://ci.athion.net/job/FastAsyncWorldEdit/ws/mvn/</url>
         </repository>

     </repositories>

    

     <dependencies>
         <dependencies>
             <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
             <artifactId>bukkit</artifactId>
             <version>VERSION</version>
             <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependencies>
             <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
             <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
             <version>LATEST</version>
             <scope>compile</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependencies>
             <groupId>com.sk89q</groupId>
             <artifactId>worldedit</artifactId>
             <version>6.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
             <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependencies>
             <groupId>com.boydti</groupId>
             <artifactId>fawe-api</artifactId>
             <version>latest</version>
             <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependencies>
             <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
             <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
             <version>1.14.8</version>
             <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependencies>
             <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
             <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
             <version>2.9.0</version>
             <scope>compile</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependencies>
             <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
             <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
             <version>LATEST</version>
             <scope>compile</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependencies>
             <groupId>pt.foxspigot.jar</groupId>
             <artifactId>FoxSpigot</artifactId>
             <version>1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
             <scope>system</scope>
             <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/foxspigot-server.jar</systemPath>
         </dependency>

     </dependencies>

     <build>
         <plugins>
             <plugins>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                 <configuration>
                     <source>1.8</source>
                     <target>1.8</target>
                 </configuration>
             </plugins>
             <plugins>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>2.1</version>
                 <executions>
                     <execution>
                         <phase>package</phase>
                         <goals>
                             <goal>shade</goal>
                         </goals>
                     </execution>
                 </executions>
             </plugins>
         </plugins>
     </build>

</project>
```